# Output the countdown has ended when countdown is zero JS

Tags: jquery, countdown

http://keith-wood.name/countdown.html

I am using this jQuery plugin.

```
$('#noDays').countdown({
    until: enddate_final, format: 'HMS', compact: true, description: '', timeSeparator: ' : '});
```

Is what I have and works fine. I wish to output "The countdown has ended" if/when the countdown is 00:00:00.

How can i do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See docs on page you posted,

Tab: `Callbacks`
Example no.3

using configuration property `expiryText`

```
$('#expireMessage').countdown({
    until: shortly.setSeconds(shortly.getSeconds() + 5.5), 
    expiryText: '<div class="over">It\'s all over</div>'
});
```